# accuracy decreases with number of folds in x-validation

Tags: neural-networks, cross-validation, scikit-learn, accuracy, tensorflow

I am running a Sequential model in Tensorflow for binary classification. I cross-validate it using sklearn's KFold with 50 folds.

The strange thing is that the binary accuracy has a trend of decreasing as the ordinal number of folds goes up, as seen in the plot below. The binary cross-entropy fluctuates without such a trend.

My understanding is that everything in each fold is independent of the others, and that the training doesn't remember previous folds as it is rebuilt inside each fold. So I am surprised to see this trend. Is there any explanation?

Edit: The sample consists of ~19,000 entries, randomly shuffled. The two classes make up 35% and 65% of the sample.

Edit: The model's architecture:

```
model = keras.Sequential([
        layers.Dense(units=200, activation='relu', input_shape=[len(f_features)]), 
        layers.Dense(units=400, activation='relu'),
        layers.Dropout(rate=0.3),  
        layers.Dense(units=400, activation='relu'),
        layers.Dropout(rate=0.3), 
        layers.Dense(units=50, activation='relu'),
        layers.Dense(units=1, activation='sigmoid') ])
```

[image: binary accuracy vs. ordinal number of folds]

Edit / update: I ran several tests with different numbers of folds. This "trend" showed up in a couple but not in most; I conclude that it was a random effect indeed.

Comment: Could you provide more details on how big your dataset is and its class proportions?

Comment: Is this time series data? If so, you should apply time-series cv. p.s. This may not explain the fluctuations.

Comment: Sorry I'm a bit confused. Is the cross entropy is computed on the fold on which the model is fitted ?

Comment: @gunes No, it isn't. Also, the data are randomly shuffled.

Comment: @mhdadk I just edited the question to give this info.

Comment: Can you please explain "Sequential model in Tensorflow for binary classification" in detail. It is hard to come up with a answer without relevant context information.

Comment: would expect if anything the accuracy to go up as  the size of the training set becomes larger.  What is meant by a "sequential" model?

Comment: @GuneykanOzkaya If you are familiar with Tensorflow, then I think that this phrase is pretty welf-explanatory :)

Comment: @DikranMarsupial The size of the training set doesn't change. If you are familiar with Tensorflow, then I think that "Sequential" is pretty well-known :)

Comment: @Helen Tensorflow can be used in wide range of problems(Function optimization, predictive modelling, etc.) and a Sequential model can be used in the context of NLP, univariate time-series, or panel time-series. Good luck solving your problem

Comment: @Pohoua In cross-validation, during each fold the model is trained on total-n samples, and then tested on the n samples.

Comment: @GuneykanOzkaya It is binary classification, the input is numerical ntuples. Nothing fancier than this.

Comment: @Helen that isn't a very helpful comment.  I understand cross-validation and was offering to help, that doesn't mean I know some jargon term for a particular package.  I am now rather less interested in helping.

Comment: @Helen, I would suggest to run cross-validation around 100 times using different seeds and plot the results again to see if you are observing the same behavior with every simulation. It is quite possible that you observe this just by chance due to the randomness of cross-validation. Alternatively, you can take the mean of the different simulations to decrease the variance due to randomness. You did not explain what your sequential model is. A sequential model can be any model. As a side note, any TF model requires numerical data; this does not give any information regarding the model

Comment: @Helen, that  does not look like KFold cross-validation, but leave-n-out xval

Comment: @DikranMarsupial I didn't mean it to sound rude, but what I was trying to say is that literally Sequential is the first thing someone learns about TensorFlow. It sould be unusual for someone to post a question about TF and explain Sequential in it. But to be more clear, it refers to the smplest kind of NN that can be built. 
As about the leave-n-out, you probably refer to my answer to Pohoua. I was trying to answer his/her question in a quick way. I am doing k-fold validation.

Comment: I don't see a trend here: a test of trend would show it indeed is down, *but not significantly so.*  In other words, your plot is not evidence of a trend up or down.

Comment: @GuneykanOzkaya Thanks, I'll try with different seeds and see. Basically I am wondering if this is some known effect (although I wouldn't expect this). If it is not, then I will know that the problem probably lies with my data. I am adding the model's architecture in the question.

Comment: @Helen, so sequential just means "feedforward"?  This forum is not specific to TensorFlow, so it is good to consider the audience of people that might want to help, that might have a great deal of experience with stats and neural nets without being experts in Tensorflow (trained my first neural net in 1988).    Is the cross-validation just used for performance evaluation or to tune some aspect of the model?

Comment: @whuber, do you mean that the fluctuation seems to be within error? (I don't know if it's Poisson error that should be applied here.) If not, and if you mean that the trend is small, I should say that my concern is not that the trend is small but that it exists...

Comment: @DikranMarsupial I see, good point. Sequential is for just stacking (feedforward) layers together. In this case it is used for performance evaluation.

Comment: Any statistical test of trend will not find this series significant at, say, a 5% level.

Comment: @Helen, in that case, I think the suggestions from Guneykan and whuber seem like the right approach, especially as the networks in each trial may end up in very different local minima, the classification error may have quite a high variance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So I think I know enough about the question to compile all the comments to a single answer.

As far as I know, there is no known effect such as "as the numbers of fold increase CV scores decrease." You usually would observe @DikranMarsupial suggested, "would expect if anything the accuracy to go up as the size of the training set becomes larger." And yes, as you increase the number of folds, your training size increases because you are dividing your data into smaller pieces. But it is also possible there is a saturation point, meaning performance does not improve after some threshold even if you add more data. Also, I agree with @whuber; there is no evident trend in your plot. If you try my previous suggestion and take the mean of all the simulations and plot them, I believe you will see that curve is smooth and no evidence of a trend.

Edit:

Then it is certain your plot is by chance. Since your data is shuffled, the order of your folds does not mean anything. You can change the order you plot the results as you wish, but you shouldn't make any conclusions based on line plots. The only thing you need to consider is the distribution of your scores. Your scores seem like they have a mean around 0.84 and vary around above the 0.80 threshold, and this is the only conclusion you should make from here. The concept of "Trend" in stats. means: a long/short term movement in an ordered series, for instance, a time series. Your scores are not an ordered series, so the trend is irrelevant.

Comment: There is something that I see was left unclear: I am not changing the number of folds; the attached plot shows the accuracy as a function of the ordinal number of folds. (I.e. 1st fold, 2nd, etc - not the total number of folds). The title was probably confusing. Having different accuracy according to the total number of folds would be expected, but here it is just that as the program keeps running later folds are performing worse than earlier ones. That being said, per your suggestion I had a look at randomness and found something (see next comment).

Comment: When the attached plot was produced, I had the input data shuffled randomly before running the x-validation and building the model. However, the shuffle of the KFold module itself was turned off. Well, I turned it on and repeated on a few different numbers of folds, and the downward trend disappeared. This might be a big coincidence, it might not; more tests will tell, as you suggested.

Comment: @Helen please see the edit

Comment: I very rarely look at the accuracy for each fold in cross-validation, just the mean and some indication of the spread, it doesn't seem a very useful diagnostic unless you are testing the code for performing the cross-validation itself.

Comment: @DikranMarsupial I agree, thats why I said: "The only thing you need to consider is the distribution of your scores. Your scores seem like they have a mean around 0.84 and vary around above the 0.80 threshold, and this is the only conclusion you should make from here."

Comment: I ran more tests and soon saw that the "trend" appears only in few of them, in a way that makes their occurrence look random. However, for the completeness of the discussion, I'd like to scrutinise a little this point: "Your scores seem like they have a mean around 0.84 and vary around above the 0.80 threshold, and this is the only conclusion you should make from here". @DikranMarsupial also wrote "just the mean and some indication of the spread". Hypothetically, if there was indeed a trend, then it seems to me that the mean and the variance alone wouldn't help to indicate its presence.

Comment: @Helen, my point was that if the folds are indeed independent random partitions of the data, then there will be no trend, even if there is a spurious appearance of a trend.  It is best to looks just at the mean and variance because otherwise it is tempting to tweak the model to fix apparent problems in particular folds, which tends to end up over-fitting the noise in the cross-validation estimator and ending up with a bad model.